# How to make line chart start from 0 X-Axis

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010, charts

I create a line chart, but I want to display the chart begin from 0 in X-axis.
How can I do this.

I try some method but still did not get what I want.

```
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 0;

Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IsStartedFromZero = true;

Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 0;

Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Crossing = 0;
```

This is what I do now

[image]

This is what I want

[image]

And one more, how can I set major and minor unit in the chart..?

my code here

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Drawing.Font axisFont = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 8, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);
        System.Drawing.Font titleFont = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 10, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);

        Chart1.Width = 600;
        Chart1.Height = 400;
        Chart1.BorderlineColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
        Chart1.BorderlineWidth = 1;
        Chart1.BorderlineDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Solid;

        double[] min = { 60.9, 0, 28.81, 7.27 };
        double[] ave = { 60.9, 0, 28.81, 7.27 };
        double[] max = { 5167.72, 1.27, 4176.16, 2566.59 };


        Chart1.Series["Series1"].ChartArea = "ChartArea1";
        Chart1.Series["Series2"].ChartArea = "ChartArea1";
        Chart1.Series["Series3"].ChartArea = "ChartArea1";

        Chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY("Step 1-2", max[0]);
        Chart1.Series["Series2"].Points.AddXY("Step 1-2", ave[0]);
        Chart1.Series["Series3"].Points.AddXY("Step 1-2", min[0]);

        Chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY("Step 2-3", max[1]);
        Chart1.Series["Series2"].Points.AddXY("Step 2-3", ave[1]);
        Chart1.Series["Series3"].Points.AddXY("Step 2-3", min[1]);

        Chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY("Step 3-4", max[2]);
        Chart1.Series["Series2"].Points.AddXY("Step 3-4", ave[2]);
        Chart1.Series["Series3"].Points.AddXY("Step 3-4", min[2]);

        Chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY("Step 4-5", max[3]);
        Chart1.Series["Series2"].Points.AddXY("Step 4-5", ave[3]);
        Chart1.Series["Series3"].Points.AddXY("Step 4-5", min[3]);
        String hour1 = "hh";
        Chart1.Titles.Add("Cycle Time : "+hour1);
        Chart1.Titles[0].Font = titleFont;

        Chart1.Series["Series1"].MarkerStyle = System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.MarkerStyle.Triangle;
        Chart1.Series["Series2"].MarkerStyle = System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.MarkerStyle.Square;
        Chart1.Series["Series3"].MarkerStyle = System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.MarkerStyle.Diamond;
        Chart1.Series["Series1"].MarkerSize = 15;
        Chart1.Series["Series2"].MarkerSize = 15;
        Chart1.Series["Series3"].MarkerSize = 15;
        Chart1.Legends.Add("Legend1");


        Chart1.Series["Series1"].LegendText = "Max";
        Chart1.Series["Series2"].LegendText = "Ave";
        Chart1.Series["Series3"].LegendText = "Min";

        Chart1.Series["Series1"].Legend = "Legend1";
        Chart1.Series["Series2"].Legend = "Legend1";
        Chart1.Series["Series3"].Legend = "Legend1";
        Chart1.Series["Series1"].IsVisibleInLegend = true;
        Chart1.Series["Series2"].IsVisibleInLegend = true;
        Chart1.Series["Series3"].IsVisibleInLegend = true;

         //This part I try to make the graph start from 0 in X-axis but not work
        //Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 0;
        //Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IsStartedFromZero = true;
        //Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 0;
        //Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Crossing = 0;
        //Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 0;
        //Chart1.ChartAreas[0].Position.Auto = false;


        Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.TitleFont = axisFont;
        Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.TitleFont = axisFont;

        Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Title = "Step";
        Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Title = "Time (" + hour1 + ")";


        Chart1.ChartAreas[0].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.AliceBlue;
        Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
        Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#D5E8F5");


    }
```

Comment: Could you add some code to show how you bind data to the chart?

Comment: Hi @fra9001 I already add my code to the question.

Comment: +1 for adding the code you are working on.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I had a similar issue, and found that the solution was to set the IsMarginVisible flag to false:

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IsMarginVisible = false;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

The Chart control decides by his own where to start the Axes, and more importantly where to end them, because it could create problems in displaying the points.

Say that you have a point in (-1,0), if you decided to start the X-Axis from 0 what should the chart control do? Display the series starting from unknown? Erase the point?

In your chart every point has 2 values, a string value for the X-Axis and a double for the Y-Axis.

The strings are stored in the chart in alphabetical order, and it also checks whether some are equals or not (so you don't have 3 *Step 1-3*s).

It also give the strings a position value, starting obviously from 0.

But what is the 0 position value string?

Answer: there is no 0 position value string possible.

In fact, if you try something like

```
        Chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(string.Empty, 1.0);
        Chart1.Series["Series2"].Points.AddXY(string.Empty, 2.0);
        Chart1.Series["Series3"].Points.AddXY(string.Empty, 3.0);
```

The chart control will automatically add a label for the empty string called 1, showing the position value.

The only way for setting major and minor unit in the chart is by adding or removing data from the chart.

Another workaround could be this:

```
Chart1.Series["SeriesMin"].Points.AddXY(0, max[0]);
Chart1.Series["SeriesAve"].Points.AddXY(0, ave[0]);
Chart1.Series["SeriesMax"].Points.AddXY(0, min[0]);

Chart1.Series["SeriesMin"].Points[0].AxisLabel = "Step 1-2";
Chart1.Series["SeriesAve"].Points[0].AxisLabel = "Step 1-2";
Chart1.Series["SeriesMax"].Points[0].AxisLabel = "Step 1-2";
```

Then you could add all your so far not working code

```
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 0;
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IsStartedFromZero = true;
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 0;
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Crossing = 0;
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 0;
//Chart1.ChartAreas[0].Position.Auto = false; //EXCEPT THIS ONE!!
```

[Worked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zptb0.jpg) like a charm, exceedingly boring if you had to add more data not from a db.