# C# - How do you make a chart object start at 0 on the X axis?

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, charts

I've been trying to set the position on the X axis from which the data starts getting plotted with no luck. It always start at 1 no matter what. I've tried doing

```
chartArea.AxisX.Minimum = -1;
chartArea.AxisX.Maximum = 5;
```

But it doesn't work. Even if I do:

```
chartArea.AxisX.Minimum = 3;
chartArea.AxisX.Maximum = 6;
```

The bars will be invisible rather than start at 3.

```
manaCurveChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IsStartedFromZero = true;
```

Doesn't seem to do anything either.

EDIT: Here's the code

```
            ChartArea chartArea = manaCurveChart.ChartAreas[0];
            chartArea.AxisX.IsStartedFromZero = true;
            chartArea.AxisX.Minimum = -1;
            chartArea.AxisX.Maximum = 5;

            string[] Pets = new string[] { "Dog", "Cat" };
            int[] PointArray = new int[] { 1, 2 };

            manaCurveChart.Titles.Add("Pets");
            for (int i = 0; i < Pets.Length; i++)
            {
                Series series = manaCurveChart.Series.Add(Pets[i]);
                series.Points.Add(PointArray[i]);
            }
```

Comment: Post code of where you set up the chart, and where you add points to the chart.

Comment: @mmathis Here is the code

Comment: Post it in the original post as an edit, so you can format it nicely

Comment: @mmathis My bad, I just posted it above.

Comment: I answered a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23750220/how-to-make-line-chart-start-from-0-x-axis/23786341#23786341) explaining how the chart control overrides your instructions to display better the charts

Comment: @fra9001 The difference here is that he's not working with string values on the axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of doing

```
series.Points.Add(PointArray[i]);
```

(where the x value is determined automatically), use

```
series.Points.AddXY(i, PointArray[i]);
```

so the x value is specified explicitly. It forces the x axis to have a minimum of 0, and you can then set your min/max/intervals as desired (or leave them to be determined automatically).

Comment: Thank you very much! I was beginning to think I was never going to get an answer anymore. It works exactly like I want it to now!