# C# chart How to Set start points of X axis

Tags: c#, sql-server, charts

I am working with C# chart and ref. to [C# - How do you make a chart object start at 0 on the X axis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23912573/c-sharp-how-do-you-make-a-chart-object-start-at-0-on-the-x-axis)

Here is my sample data :

```
     X        Value ( From _LOWER )
======================
    0           0
    0.5        100
    1.0        200
    1.5        300
    2.0        400
    2.5        500
    4.0        600
    5.0        700
    7.5        800
    10.0       900
    12.5       1000
```

I am using following code :

```
chart1.Series.Clear();
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Interval = 200;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval =  0.5;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalAutoMode = IntervalAutoMode.VariableCount ;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Number;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 0;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IsStartedFromZero = true;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = 0;

chart1.Series.Add("Trial 1");
chart1.Series["Trial 1"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
chart1.Series["Trial 1"].BorderWidth = 2;
chart1.Series["Trial 1"].XValueType = ChartValueType.String;
chart1.Series["Trial 1"].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;

this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineDashStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartDashStyle.DashDotDot;
this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineDashStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartDashStyle.DashDotDot;
this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].IsSameFontSizeForAllAxes = true;

DataRowCollection _dr = _CObjectsofClasses._obj_CDatabase._MGetDataRows("select _LOWER from tblCHART ORDER BY [_CHARTID]");
foreach (DataRow _drRow in _dr)
   {
     chart1.Series["Trial 1"].Points.AddY(_drRow[0]);
   }
```

And here is the output

[image: Chart Out Put]

As you see in the chart the values start from 1, but it should be started from 0, as shown in chart 100 is displayed on 2 instead of 0.5, 200 is displayed on 3 instead on 1 and so on....

please suggest me where I am wrong.

**Update**

If I use code (Adding XY axis)

```
DataRowCollection _dr =    _CObjectsofClasses._obj_CDatabase._MGetDataRows("select _SNAME, _LOWER from tblCHART ORDER BY [_CHARTID]");
foreach (DataRow _drRow in _dr)
{  
   chart1.Series["Trial 1"].Points.AddXY(_drRow[0], _drRow[1]);
}
```

then I am getting output

[image]

not getting 0.5 intervals and zero showing 2 times

Comment: Use Points.AddXY to explicitly set the x-values instead of Points.AddY !

Comment: @Taw also tried but its changed X axis labels as in my sample data, means 2.0, 4.0, 5.0 etc, and not as in 0.5 interval as show in chart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want control over the `X-Values` you should add the `DataPoints` using the `AddXY` method.

using this

```
for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) chart1.Series["Trial 1"].Points.AddY(i * 50);
```

or this

```
for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) chart1.Series["Trial 1"].Points.AddXY(i, i * 50);
```

results in these two charts..:

[image][image]

All the rest is your code. (The size difference is just from manual resizing..)

It is worth looking into the `X-Values` of the first version: They all are `0`!

In your case you should write:

```
int i = 0;
foreach (DataRow _drRow in _dr)
{  
    chart1.Series["Trial 1"].Points.AddXY(i++, _drRow[1]);
}
```

Btw, you may want to rethink setting the the `X-Values` to `string`; this usually leaves you with only little control..

Answer (score 1):

After using AddXY to set x/y points, change your minimum value to double.NaN and set IsMarginVisible to false

```
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = double.NaN;
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IsMarginVisible = false;
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = double.NaN;
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.IsMarginVisible = false;
```