# draw line chart from maximum point y axis

Tags: c#, winforms, mschart

I have a line chart in my form that get its data by the code comes in the following

```
foreach (var series in chart2.Series)
{
       series.Points.Clear();
}

Series series2 = chart2.Series[0];
SqlCommand cmdchartline = new SqlCommand(myquery, Con);
SqlDataReader reader2 = cmdchartline.ExecuteReader();

while (reader2.Read())
{
   chart2.Series[0].Points.AddXY(reader2["myx"].ToString(), reader2["myy"]);
}
```

I need to connect (0,5000) as a first point to the chart below I mean chart start from (0,5000) on Y axis

[image: how can I add 0,5000 as a first point to the chart]

Comment: Is the data just not being showing up?  I don't quite understand what your problem is.

Comment: @JonathanVanDam chart is showing up, i just need to connect maximum value of y axis to it

Comment: Perhaps it's the XValueType is set up wrong.  This would cause all points to be in the same location, thus not making a line.

Comment: @JonathanVanDam no i do not think so because I have a correct line and correct value axies

Comment: Ok then it's not that.  I'm sorry but I just don't get what you are trying to do.

Comment: @JonathanVanDam    I create a line chart that gets its value from two table fields and show up on form correctly but I need just add another point to it which is maximum value of Y axis.

Answer (score 2):

You are adding the x-values as **strings**.

This is usually  (*) wrong as they all are `0` now.

Note: The labels still **show** the strings but otherwise they are **useless**.

Change this

```
chart2.Series[0].Points.AddXY(reader2["myx"].ToString(), reader2["myy"]);
```

to this:

```
chart2.Series[0].Points.AddXY(reader2["myx"], reader2["myy"]);
```

If the fields 'myx' and 'myy' are numbers or dates you now can find the maximum for the `DataPoint` values:

```
double maxX =  chart2.Series[0].Points.Max(x => x.XValues);
double maxY =  chart2.Series[0].Points.Max(x => x.YValues[0]);
```

Now you can add (or insert) the **extra** `DataPoint`; you need to decide on its x-value though!

As I wrote the finding the Y-value is simple but the x-values may be less simple. If you don't need the x-values you can keep them as string or, better, you can make the Series 'Indexed'..:

```
chart2.Series[0].IsXValueIndexed  = true;
```

Then you can **insert** the extra point to the beginning like this:

```
chart2.Series[0].Points.InsertXY(0, 0, maxY);
```

Note that when keeping the x-values as strings you can't:

- use a formatting string for the axis or datapoint labels
- use a zoom range based on the values (Axis.ScaleView)
- use a display range (Axis.Minimum/Maximum)
- do any calulations with the x-values

And you can't hope the chart would display the values in a nice proportional manner; instead they will have sit at the same intervals.

(*) Sometimes none of this is needed, like when the x-values are names or persons or cities etc..

Comment: many thanks for taking time. X axis is based on date and Y is values. and both axis start with 0. I have Y max value on a label. but when I use
chart2.Series[0].Points.AddXY(0,Convert.ToInt16(lbl1.Text));it add another point that I do not need. Indeed I need  0,max(yvalue) as a first point.

Comment: I need connect (0,5000) as a first point to the chart above that I showed up

Comment: It just add another point on the chart that I won't cause i could do that in other way. I want my chart start from maximum point on Y axis

Comment: Well, that is what the new point __inserted__ (nor __addedd__!!) at the start will do, no? Do note the the '0' you keep talking about doesn't really exist in your chart. The one you see is from the y-axis. Maybe you should draw the missing line inothe screenshot, so I can see better what you want.

Comment: Thank you, finally I could find my answer at this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23750220/how-to-make-line-chart-start-from-0-x-axis

Comment: Lol. Good to hear you think you got what you want. But this has really nothing to do with what you asked here!