# Charting hours wont start at zero

Tags: c#, charts

I have a chart control on a winform that should log some counting p hour.
On 12H clock repeat in local PC time.
 
So the chart starts from 0 to 11 
The problem is that when its 12:20 or 12:50 or 12:10
I cannot get the numbering to start at 0 on the X axis

My main inits the chart like :

```
int[] numbers = new int[11] {12,11,10,91,82,7,66,5,44,3,2,1};
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = 11;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 0;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;
```

Then a loop updates and redraws the chart like below

```
DateTime  currentTime = DateTime.UtcNow.ToLocalTime();
int hour12 = (currentTime.Hour % 12);
numbers[hour12]++;    
chart1.Series["total"].Points.DataBindY(numbers);
```

I also tried but it didnt help here.

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IsMarginVisible = false;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make line chart start from 0 X-Axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23750220/how-to-make-line-chart-start-from-0-x-axis)

Comment: well i would wish so, but that solution doesnt work, i tried it too before posting.

Comment: how about `DataBindXY`?

Comment: As you don't set any x-values they all are `0`. The labels enumerate the points, starting from `1`. That is how it is. Set the x-values if you want to see other numbers!

Comment: nope, I increase the current hourly value in this line: numbers[hour12]++;  that does increase the array item at position hour with one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
chart1.Series["total"].Points.DataBindY(numbers);
```

with

```
chart1.Series["total"].Points.DataBindXY(Enumerable.Range(0,12).ToArray(), numbers);
```

Update:
Set AxisX so that all chart series shows up correctly:

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = 12;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum =-1;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;
```

Comment: that results in System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException 
which it doesnt when i dont replace that line

Comment: Try `Enumerable.Range(0,12).ToArray()`. Also this line of yours `int[] numbers = new int[11] {12,11,10,91,82,7,66,5,44,3,2,1};` doesn't compile either as you are initialising an 11 position int array with 12 ints

Comment: array pos starts at zero you can do numbers[0] = 1;

Comment: Are you suggesting that this line `int[] numbers = new int[11] {12,11,10,91,82,7,66,5,44,3,2,1};` is compiling on your visual studio?

Comment: strangely though changing your line (0,12) did have effect. But with a catch.. i'm displaying 3 bars on my graph per hour (red gren orange), the first bar isnt shown, as it drops out of the viewable area of the chart

Comment: that's because you've miscalculated the axis X numbering...set `chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = 12;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149224/discussion-between-sakis-and-user3800527).

Comment: Well its not because of that i tried, 
i want it to start at 0, but the vertical grid line of zero should be pushed a bit to the right (without having it to start at -1) so that it can display the bars.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Sakis to remove -1 and 12 to get the 0..11 scale.

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = 12;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum =-1;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(-1.5, -0.5, "Hour");
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(11.5, 12.5, "   ");
for(int i=0;i<12;i++)   chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(i-0.9, i+0.9, i.ToString());
```